# ZF3 Get browser Language

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

There are a several of ways to get the browser language in Zend Framework 3. Can anyone tell me what should be the right way ?

I was thinking about getting the locale and substract the language from it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->request->getHeader('Accept-Language')->getPrioritized()[0]->getPrimaryTag();
```

or

```
$this->request->getHeader('Accept-Language')->getPrioritized()[0]->getLanguage();
```

Comment: Yes I figuiered that out also but only saw your post yesterday, but thanks tho! I have seen this question more so it should be helpable for more people!

Answer (score 0):

In ZF 2 , somewhere in Controller

```
$translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
    $t  = $translator->getLocale();
```

Comment: In zf3 serviceLocator is deprecated, this will not work.

Comment: Deprecated since ZF2.5