# ZF3 get date/time format based on locale

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm looking for a way to get the date and time or date/time format based on the user locale I have.

Like:

de_DE will have d-m-Y (21-10-2017)
en_US will have Y/m/d (2017/10/21)

Is there a way in ZF3 to get this or do I need to use some PHP based solution ?

It's not the idea to get the anything formatted but the format itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797651/zf3-get-browser-language isn't that previous question of yours related? you even received 2 answers but didn't say/do anything.

Comment: I just saw the reactions yesterday but it's not related to my previous question, if it was it would have been perfect!

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is the [zend-i18n view helpers](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-i18n/view-helpers/#dateformat-helper).

> If unset, it will use the default locale (return value of Locale::getDefault()).

So if you use it without setting the last parameter, you should be able to use the language defined in your previous topic!